# Disabling Buttons if edittext is empty on a custom dialog

Tags: android

Can someone please help me fix my code I am trying to disable the `Button` if 'to' and 'text' aren't entered into the `EditText` fields.  This line

`post_button.setEnabled(false);`

gives me the error

```
cannot resolve symbol
```

as I have set this in the `Dialog`. How do I work around this to achieve this.

```
     newMessage.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            final Dialog dialog = new Dialog(context);

            dialog.setContentView(R.layout.write_message_layout);

            final TextView post_button = (TextView) dialog.findViewById(R.id.button_post);
            final TextView cancel_button = (TextView) dialog.findViewById(R.id.message_cancel);
            final EditText new_message_text = (EditText) dialog.findViewById(R.id.new_message_insert_text);
            final EditText new_message_to = (EditText) dialog.findViewById(R.id.new_message_insert_to);
            //final EditText
            // = (EditText) dialog.findViewById(R.id.new_message_insert_to);

            cancel_button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    dialog.cancel();
                }
            });
                            post_button.setEnabled(!TextUtils.isEmpty(new_message_to.getText().toString()));
            post_button.setEnabled(!TextUtils.isEmpty(new_message_text.getText().toString()));


            ///
            new_message_to.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
                @Override
                public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {
                    post_button.setEnabled(count > 0);
                }
                @Override
                public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) { }
                @Override
                public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
                }
            });


            new_message_text.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
                @Override
                public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s1, int start1, int before1, int count1) {
                    post_button.setEnabled(count1 > 0);
                }
                @Override
                public void beforeTextChanged (CharSequence s1, int start1, int count1, int after1) { }
                @Override
                public void afterTextChanged(Editable s1) {
                }
            });

            post_button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {


                    items.add(new MessageItem(55, new_message_to.getText().toString(), "image", DateTime.now(), new_message_text.getText().toString()));

                    itemAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

                    if (v.getId() == R.id.button_post);
                    new_message_to.setText("");
                    new_message_text.setText("");


                    dialog.dismiss();

                }
            });

            dialog.show();
        }
    });

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a TextWatcher for your EditText, and check the count paramter to enabled/disable the button: e.g

```
new_message_to.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
    @Override
    public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) { 
         yourButton.setEnabled(count > 0);
    }
    @Override
    public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) { }
    @Override
    public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
    }
});
```

Edit:

```
post_button.setEnabled(!TextUtils.isEmpty(new_message_to.getText().toString()) && !TextUtils.isEmpty(new_message_text.getText().toString()));
```

in `new_message_to onTextChanged` you check:

```
 post_button.setEnabled(count > 0 && !TextUtils.isEmpty(new_message_text.getText().toString()));
```

in new_message_text onTextChage you check:

```
 post_button.setEnabled(count > 0 && !TextUtils.isEmpty(new_message_to.getText().toString()));
```

Comment: He has a `TextWatcher` orb just not attached to the `EditText` and the `Button` is out of scope because it's in the dialog

Comment: lol orb! Thanks. But then the problem is just scope related, isn't it? @codeMagic

Comment: where abouts should i put this in my code - should I also delete parts in the code above?

Comment: It is just scope related and the fact that the `TextWatcher` isn't ever added to the `EditText`. But your answer solves that last problem

Comment: @codeMagic is right it is out of scope I want the button to be disabled if my textviews are empty - but struggling as this in in a dialog

Comment: @Sim, the easiest way is to move it after the field initialization, just like you do for the cancel_button field

Comment: That way also keeps you from creating an unnecessary scope for the variable because you don't need to make a member variable. I do what I can rob

Comment: I've updated my code the way I think you meant but it still allows me to press the button without entering data in the edittext fields - can you please check this for me - thank you in adv

Comment: I've adjusted the code again but I'm still able to click the post button with the new_message_to being empty - please help me to understand why it isn't working :(

Comment: Thank you so much for your time that works great - if I want to so this for the new_message_text as well I assumed it would be the same code but this doesn't seem to do the job (updated my code in the question)

Comment: Yes so I want text to be inputted in the new_message_to and new_message_text before the post_button can be clicked

Answer (score 0):

You're getting that error because `post_button, new_message_text, andnew_message_to` do not exist within the scope of your `TextWatcher`.

Since you're declaring them as final variables inside a method, only that method (or anonymous inner methods directly nested within it) will have access to said variables.

If you want it to work, you have two options:

1. Make `post_button` and other variables globally accessible
2. Pass `post_button` and other variables to your `TextWatcher`

The former is simplest, so, your code would become:

```
private TextView post_button;
private EditText new_message_text;
private EditText new_message_to;

public void showCustomDialog(){
    final Dialog dialog = new Dialog(context);
    dialog.setContentView(R.layout.write_message_layout);

    post_button = (TextView) dialog.findViewById(R.id.button_post);
    final TextView cancel_button = (TextView) dialog.findViewById(R.id.message_cancel);
    new_message_text = (EditText) dialog.findViewById(R.id.new_message_insert_text);
    new_message_to = (EditText) dialog.findViewById(R.id.new_message_insert_to);

    cancel_button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            dialog.cancel();
        }
    });

    post_button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            items.add(new MessageItem(55, new_message_to.getText().toString(), "image", DateTime.now(), new_message_text.getText().toString()));

            itemAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

            if (v.getId() == R.id.button_post);
            new_message_to.setText("");
            new_message_text.setText("");

            dialog.dismiss();
        }
    });

    new_message_text.addTextChangeListener(textWatcher);
    new_message_to.addTextChangeListener(textWatcher);

    dialog.show();

    new_message_to.setText(""); // Trigger your TextWatcher's event listener
}

private TextWatcher textWatcher = new TextWatcher() {
    @Override
    public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence charSequence, int i, int i2, int i3) { }

    @Override
    public void onTextChanged(CharSequence charSequence, int i, int i2, int i3){
        String s1 = new_message_to.getText().toString();
        String s2 = new_message_text.getText().toString();

        if (s1.equals("") || s2.equals("")) post_button.setEnabled(false);
        else post_button.setEnabled(true);
    }

    @Override
    public void afterTextChanged(Editable editable) { }
};
```

Someone else also noted you never added the TextWatcher, so I did that.

Comment: Sorry I added that and it still doesn't disable the button

Comment: If you call setText("") on either of your buttons, it will. You need the TextWatcher's onTextChanged event to actually be triggered in order for your check to actually disable the buttons. I guess I should have written that... Going to edit it in for you.